# How to assign value to a variable from http response in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I want to assign value to a variable from http response. In console http response shows the value but the variable shows undefined. The variable is a type of a class.

**order.model.ts**

```
import { OrderItem } from './order-item.model';
export class Order {
    OrderId:number;
    OrderNo :string;
    PMethod :String;
    GTotal :number;
    CustomerId :number;
    OrderItems:OrderItem[];    
}
```

**order-item.model.ts**

```
export class OrderItem {
    orderItemId:number;   
    itemId:number;
    quantity:number;
    itemName: string;
    price: number;
    total:number;
}
```

**order.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from '../_models/order.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderService {

  formData:Order;
  baseUrl = environment.apiURL;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getSingleOrder(id:number){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+ 'order/'+id);
  }

}
```

**sorder.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderService } from 'src/app/_services/order.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Order } from 'src/app/_models/order.model';


@Component({
selector: 'app-sorder',
  templateUrl: './sorder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sorder.component.css']
})
export class SorderComponent implements OnInit
{
    constructor(private orderService:OrderService ) { }

  ngOnInit()
{
    let orderId = this.currentRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    if (orderId == null)
    {
        this.formDataReset();
    }
    else
    {
        this.getOrderDetail(parseInt(orderId));
    }
}

formDataReset()
{
    this.orderService.formData = {
    OrderId: 0,
      OrderNo: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000).toString(),
      CustomerId: 0,
      PMethod: '',
      GTotal: 0,
      OrderItems:[],      
    }
}

getOrderDetail(id:number)
{
    this.orderService.getSingleOrder(id).subscribe((res: Order)=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.orderService.formData = res;
        console.log(this.orderService.formData.OrderId);
    }
    error =>
    {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

}
```

**console.log(res):**

```
{orderID: 10, orderNo: "161235", pMethod: "Cash", gTotal: 22.42, customerID: 5, …}
customerID: 5
gTotal: 22.42
orderID: 10
orderItems: Array(2)
0:
itemID: 9
name: "Onion Rings"
orderItemID: 5
price: 2.99
quantity: 5
total: 14.950000000000001
__proto__: Object
1:
itemID: 11
name: "Sweet Potato Fries"
orderItemID: 6
price: 2.49
quantity: 3
total: 7.470000000000001
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
orderNo: "161235"
pMethod: "Cash"
__proto__: Object
```

**console.log(this.orderService.formData.OrderId):**

```
undefined
```

I want the variable formdata shows the value which i get from http response i,e

```
 OrderId:10;
    OrderNo :"161235";
    PMethod :"Cash";
    GTotal :22.42;
    CustomerId :5;
    OrderItems:[
{orderItemID: 5, quantity: 5, itemID: 9, name: "Onion Rings", price: 2.99, …}
{orderItemID: 6, quantity: 3, itemID: 11, name: "Sweet Potato Fries", price: 2.49, …}
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is result of `console.log(this.orderService.formData)`?

Comment: Looks like you're using a Template Driven Form. Also, since you have a data-model in place, you should consider using a reactive form instead. Do you have a Sample StackBlitz to work with?

Comment: Result of console.log(this.orderService.formData) is Undefined. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: No. @SiddAjmera

Comment: @SkAbidAhmed, can you create one?

Comment: Look at your logs. Your field is actually named `orderID`, but you're trying to access `OrderId`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. Respect the naming conventions everywhere, and everything will be easier. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed with you, but for that it must prints the value for formData? As OP said `(In comment)`: *console.log(this.orderService.formData) is Undefined.*

Comment: No. Read the code. The code is `console.log(this.orderService.formData.OrderId);`. So what is underfined is `this.orderService.formData.OrderId`.

Comment: @SkAbidAhmed, I'd suggest you to create one in that case and share it across so that somebody could help. You'd end up running in circles otherwise.

Comment: I do not understand from where the name "orderID" come from. In my database field name is "OrderId".  @JB Nizet

Comment: If I change my model class field as per log it works. @JBNizet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your interface to:

```
export class Order {
orderItemID:number;
orderNo:string;
pMethod:String;
gTotal :number;
customerID :number;
orderItems:OrderItem[];
total?: number;
quantity?: number;
price? : number;
name? : string;
itemID? : number
```

}

Your Order interface and "response" type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But i do not understand from where the field name comes. In my database the field is same as my interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `set` and `get` method in your service class.

In your orderService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Order } from '../_models/order.model';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderService {

  formData: any;
  baseUrl = environment.apiURL;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getSingleOrder(id:number){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl+ 'order/'+id);
  }

  setFormData(data) {
    this.formData = data;
   }


   getFormData() {
    return this.formData;
   }

}
```

In your sorder.component.ts

```
getOrderDetail(id:number)
{
    this.orderService.getSingleOrder(id).subscribe((res: Order)=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.orderService.setFormData(res);
        console.log(this.orderService.getFormData());
    }
    error =>
    {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but still the result is undefined.

Comment: can you try this in-service class

formData: any;

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because in response you are getting 'orderId' and your are accessing 'OrderId'.